# {Sidewaystable} appears too far left and does not respect margins set with {geometry}

Tags: tables, positioning

I'm using the sidewaystable environment because the table is too long to fit portrait-wise on the page, so it must go landscape.

It appears in the correct place in the text, but appears too far to the left on the page.

The whole document has a 45mm left-margin (PhD thesis using the report class) throughout (printing regulations for my college), but the sidewaystable isn't respecting this. I've set the margins using the {geometry} package.

How do I align the 'top' of the table 45mm from the left of the page like all the text is?

Comment: please add a minimal working example...

Comment: You don't have to use the actual table.  A \rule the same size will do.

Comment: Which document class do you employ?

Comment: Hi @Mico. Report.

Comment: I had the same issue and decided to use the `longtable` package alongside the `pdflscape` package instead. This also allows the a table to be spread across multiple pages. Both seem to work with the `geometry` package without issue.